# Create list from sqlite database join function

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to make a list from a sqlite database join. I'd like to get the date values when the specific machine is selected. Example: Machine A is selected, it makes a list of 05/25/15, 05/30/15, 05/20/15. With the join I'm using it wants to spit out the column name but not the values. It's an ambiguous column error with sqlite.

[image]

```
   void fill_listbox_Dates()
    {
        string Machine_Name_listbox = listboxMachines.SelectedItem.ToString();

        string databaseString = "datasource=LinacDatabase.db";

        string DateQuery = "SELECT Date FROM Machines as E1 INNER JOIN Date as E2 ON Machines.Machine= " + Machine_Name_listbox + "";

        SQLiteConnection conDatabase = new SQLiteConnection(databaseString);
        SQLiteCommand cmdDataBase = new SQLiteCommand(DateQuery, conDatabase);
        SQLiteDataReader ReadDate;

        try
        {

            conDatabase.Open();
            ReadDate = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (ReadDate.Read())
            {
                List<string> Dates = ReadDate.GetString(1);

                listboxDates.Items.Add(Dates);
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you are doing a `join`, where is your second table?

Comment: That's what has me a little confused. It's only one table but I want to make a column of just the dates for machine A. So I just did a join for the same table to see if it would work.

Comment: Your query looks very weird, I think you probably want "select Date from Machines where Machine = '"+ Machind_Name_listbox  + "'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I had to insert a single quote value around to double quote of the Machine_Name_List box string. Otherwise the sqlite datareader will think the value is a column name. So it should read,

```
string DateQuery = "SELECT Date FROM Machines as E1 INNER JOIN Date as E2 ON Machines.Machine= '" + Machine_Name_listbox + "'";
```